# Why is flex:1 exceeding parent space in Chrome and here (snippet), but not in Firefox?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I reduced my problem to the minimum below. The canvas (red) should not exceed it's parent space (body, blue), because the flex:1 should make it increase to the size of the remaining space, and not after it. Even if I use flex:1 1 auto, which should include the flex-shrink, it still doesn't work in Chrome or here (i.e. the red rectangle overgrows the blue one). But it works perfectly in Firefox.

What I see in Chrome:

[image: Chrome screen]

What I see in Firefox:

[image: Firefox screen]

Depending on the size of your screen, you must change the values of min-width and max-width to see the error.

Can anybody please explain what's wrong?

```js
var cnv,ctx;
cnv = document.getElementById('cnv');
ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
W = cnv.offsetWidth;
H = cnv.offsetHeight;
cnv.width = W;
cnv.height = H;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.strokeRect(0,0,W,H);
ctx.font = '18px sans-serif';
ctx.fillText(W,W/2,H/2);
```

```css
html {
    height:90%;
    width:90%;
    border:5px solid yellow;
}
body {
    height:90%;
    width:90%;
    border:5px solid blue;
    margin:0;
    display:flex;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height:0;
}
nav {
    background:#99bb55;
    width:300px;
    flex-shrink:0;
    min-height:0;
}
#cnv {
    flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav></nav>
  <canvas id='cnv'></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: You’re doing several unexpected things here. Why are you setting `min-width` and `max-width` to `500px`, instead of just setting `width: 500px`? Also, [canvas elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) expect to be given a width and height, whereas it seems you are wanting one with responsive dimensions? Wouldn’t that distort your drawing if your canvas size changes?

Comment: @BrettDonald 1) I used min and max width to be sure that the nav's width won't change if the content changes. But using "width" alone doesn't seem to solve the problem. 2) Yes, it distorts, but then I redraw it after every window resize. I want the canvas to fully occupy all the remaining space after the nav (it's a mapping app).

Comment: I would recommend setting `width` and `flex-shrink: 0` rather than `min-width` and `max-width`.

Comment: @BrettDonald Done. But it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I know. That’s why I’ve not posted an answer 

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue arises because if you don’t give a `canvas` element a specific width or height, the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#the-canvas-element) defines a default width (300px) and height (150px). This is clearly different from a regular `div`, which has no default size. I suspect you need to be styling the `canvas` with a width and height in order to override these defaults.

I also prefer a grid over a flexbox for building two-column layouts, particularly in scenarios where you want the child elements to fit the container.

```js
var cnv,ctx;
cnv = document.getElementById('cnv');
ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
W = cnv.offsetWidth;
H = cnv.offsetHeight;
cnv.width = W;
cnv.height = H;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.strokeRect(0,0,W,H);
ctx.font = '18px sans-serif';
ctx.fillText(W,W/2,H/2);
```

```css
body {
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 50vh;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px auto;
}

nav {
  background: #99bb55;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav></nav>
  <canvas id='cnv'></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, Brett! I'm more used to flexbox, but I'll try your suggestion. Strange thing is, if 300px is the default width, then why in the world Chrome _expanded_ the canvas to 1375px wide?!